# what does "face" mean here?

Tags: meaning

What does "face" mean here?

> I could walk the length of Broadway ***without a face***. I could perish in  the fire and have no one to realize until a firefighter came across my teeth in the ash.

Comment: What is the source for this? Day-to-day conversation? A poem?

Comment: This quote seems to be [from the novel "Luster" by Raven Leilani](https://dearmrhemingway.com/paint-me-into-your-life/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an unusual and highly poetic usage; any meaning is unclear without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The human brain is quite good at recognizing faces - to the extend that we tend to "see" faces where there are none, for example in clouds (see [pareidolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia)). So, a large part of recognizing somebody is recognizing their face. If you don't have a face, you go unrecognized, maybe even unnoticed.

By

> I could walk the length of Broadway without a face.

the speaker means that they could walk down a big, busy street like Broadway without somebody recognizing them or maybe even without somebody noticing them.

The following sentence continues with the same idea: If the speaker were to perish in a fire, nobody would realize that they are missing, or that it was them who perished in the fire (and not somebody else). It would take a tangible proof, their teeth in the ashes, to identify them.